# ErrorException file_put_contents(/var/www/app/resources/lang/ar/messages.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel

getting this error while trying to add secondary language translation. but looks like I am having permissions issues! But i am not able to fix the issue from Terminal! Can anyone help, please
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:187
{

```
    return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);

}
```

app/Http/Controllers/adminpnlx/LanguageSettingsController.php:306
}

```
        $currLangArray  .=  ');';



        $file           =    ROOT . DS . 'resources' . DS . 'lang' . DS . $val->lang_code . DS . 'messages.php';

        File::put($file, $currLangArray);
```

app/Http/Middleware/AuthAdmin.php:22
}

```
    return $next($request);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to dynamically update the translations from within the application itself, is that correct?

The web server does not have access to write to that file, by design. It's very insecure.  You could define another disk in app/config/filesystems.php to write to it, but I would not recommend it. You could also change the permissions on the /resources/lang directory, but again, this feels very hacky and I would not recommend it.

If I were going to add translations from the application itself, I'd write the strings to the database and then write a function to load them in the actual language translation files, or write something to bypass them altogether.  I also found a package here: https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable.  It doesn't appear to be recently updated, but it may at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, the way we do this is updating lang from the application yes . I actually want to find a better way to do this and just u gave me a suggestion i will check that as well

Comment: What are the secure options to create multilingual application?